# Crash trying to access static property before an instance is allocated

Tags: objective-c, ios, cmmotionmanager

I'm using core motion in my app. This code works fine:

```
motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
int a = [CMMotionManager availableAttitudeReferenceFrames];
```

This code crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS, with this note above the line: **THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY**_YOU_MUST_EXEC__

```
int a = [CMMotionManager availableAttitudeReferenceFrames];
motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
```

I can get around the problem by using the first ordering of statements, but since availableAttitudeReferenceFrames is defined as

```
+ (NSUInteger)availableAttitudeReferenceFrames
```

it seems like I should be able to access the property before instantiating a class. Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a rather strange error. You're only supposed to see that if you call `fork()` and then try to use CoreFoundation. Since you cannot `fork()` on iOS, then you should never see this error.

Can you reproduce this issue in a very small sample project? If you can, you should [file a bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com) with Apple and attach the sample project.